# How to detect the events of the parent control under child controls in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a custom data grid control in winform.
There is a big custom panel for background. (this is a parent)
And i add all checkbox button on the background panel.

[image]

You can see the cells and each cells are custom checkbox.
I want to make a multi drag select like Excel. 
So i subscribe event for parent panel which is under the cells. But panel can't check any mouse events. It seems that WinForm Control can't detect overlapped control's event which is placed underside.
How should i detect this underside panel's event?

Comment: I suppose you could subscribe all of the controls' MouseDown events to the same method...?

Comment: @RufusL Yes. Exactly i will subscribe just only background panel (parent). And it will get event and invoke click(or drag) each cells.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a DataGridView?  WinForms doesn't like using thousands of controls.

Comment: Because winform datagridview seems not good in design face. I Want to design all controls like visual studio 2015 dark theme. In this case maybe the telerik is the good choice. Telerik has beautiful design but it is too massive to use. So i'm gonna make a custom control library.